# How can I traverse the EMF object tree generated by Xtext?

Tags: eclipse, dsl, eclipse-emf, xtext

I'm using [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) to define my DSL. Xtext generates a parser that lets me traverse the EMF model of my input DSL. I'd like to translate this EMF model into some other tree. To do this translation, I need to traverse the tree. But, I couldn't find a visitor class for the EMF model generated by Xtext. The closest thing that I've found is a Switch class that visits a single node. I can traverse the EMF model myself and invoke the Switch class on each node that I visit. But, I wonder if there exists a visitor functionality in Xtext that implements the model traversal.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/xtext-dev/msg00018.html), Switch ([used here](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/xtext-dev/msg00017.html) for instance) is pretty much the official visitor pattern for XText.
You also have the [custom Validation process](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.tmf/org.eclipse.xtext/plugins/org.eclipse.xtext.doc/html/xtext.html?root=Modeling_Project&view=co#validation):

> The purpose of the `AbstractDeclarativeValidator` is to allow you to write constraints in a declarative way – as the class name already suggests.
>   That is instead of writing exhaustive if-else constructs or extending the generated EMF switch you just have to add the `@Check` annotation to any method and it will be invoked automatically when validation takes place.

That may be not exactly what you need, though.

Comment: @VonC, I had already read the thread you referred to. I'm well aware of the Switch class. I was just wandering if there is a class that implements the traversal logic, too.

Comment: @reprogrammer: I thought so, just wanted to point out the apparent "only XText visitor" status of Switch.

Answer (score 3):

I guess EcoreUtil.getAllProperContents(Resource, false) might be what you are looking for. You'll get a TreeIterator that will traverse the contents of the resource. Pass the result of iter.next() into a Switch and perform the transformation logic depending on the element type.

Comment: Similarly, you can get a `TreeIterator` from your model's `Resource.getAllContents()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, is it not sufficient to use EMF API? If you want to transform the model, is using some of the transformation langauges like Xtend not possible?

Comment: How would you use Xtend to transform the EMF model to another model?

Comment: @reprogrammer check out the documentation: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.xpand.doc/help/ch01s05.html